# css: set the height of floating divs as maximum of their heights with margins

Tags: css, html, height, margin

My question is based on the
[css: set the height of floating divs as maximum of their heights - Is it possible to fix this jsFiddle **with pure css** so that all 3 divs that are in the same row have the same height, the maximum of their 3 heitghts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21313424/css-set-the-height-of-floating-divs-as-maximum-of-their-heights)

The solution is [here - jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9qrwJ/).

However, I didn't mention I need some margins between elements (as not important and easy to add). As result, `display:table-cell` solution was suggested. Unfortunately, Margin property is not applicable to `display:table-cell` elements.

Is it still possible to solve my question with some space between divs **with pure css**?
The original code is here and I want the height of all three divs to be the same and they have some space in between, let's say `3px`.

The code is here:

```
<style>
#main{
    border:1px solid red;
    width:605px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#zero{
    border:1px solid blue;
}
.small{
    border:1px solid green;
    float:left;
    width:199px;
}
</style>
<div id="main">
    <div id="zero">
        0
    </div>
    <div class="small">
        small text
    </div>
    <div class="small">
        large text large textlarge textlarge textlarge textlarge textlarge textlarge textlarge textlarge textlarge textlarge textlarge text
    </div>
    <div class="small">
        another small text
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the original problem @ [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7A95U/).

Again, **I would prefer a pure css solution if it is possible**.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18346083/space-between-divs-display-table-cell

Comment: But if you consider using JS by any chance: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18362090/1725764

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `border-spacing: 3px;` on `#main`.

**[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9qrwJ/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

Hello mate I played a bit with your code and if you remove float left and add `display:table-cell;` you get the result you want.

As for the margin between divs not sure if its possible with one div class.

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/7A95U/1/

Bill.